# Difficulty sorting entries based on attributes of related models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I am having trouble implementing a feature that allows users to see questions (my model) sorted or filtered based on various attributes belonging to it (i.e. was the question answered?  how many answered per question, etc), which would be based on the `Question` model's attributes, or that of attributes of related models to `Question`.

I have the following models:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base    
  belongs_to :course
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :answers, inverse_of: :question
  belongs_to :accepted_answer, class_name: :answer, foreign_key: :accepted_answer_id

  default_scope order: 'questions.created_at DESC'
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :question, inverse_of: :answers
  has_many :a_votes

  default_scope order: 'answers.created_at DESC'

  def accepted?
    return false if new_record? 
    question.try( :accepted_answer_id ) == id
    # an alternative is to use question.try( :accepted_answer ) == self
  end
end
```

What I would be add are sorts or filters in the **controller** such as "See only answered questions", where only questions that has `question.accepted_answer == true`.  What would be the best way to achieve this?  And are there any guides that I should consult on ActiveRecord filtering/sorting that I could use for future reference?

Thanks!!

### Addendum

I am displaying the questions as rendered `_question.html.erb` and calling it via the `show` function of question's parent, `Group` (so, each `Group` will `has_many` questions)

```
class CoursesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @course = Course.find(params[:id])
    # @questions = @course.questions.all this is the default selection
    @questions = @course.questions.by_answer_count #maybe Im not calling the scope correctly (and sorry if I am making a noob mistake..)
  end
  #There are other methods not shown
end
```

Comment: I don't know if this really is what you are looking for - But looking into: https://github.com/ernie/ransack - Ransack Gem would not hurt

Comment: @MartinLang this looks really cool, and I may go with this I can't get my own sort/filter logic to work.  Thanks for sharing this cool gem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I achieve this sort of thing by defining a scope on the parent model using joins and grouping.

For example, this scope would order the questions by number of answers (descending).

```
class Question
  scope :by_answer_count, -> {
    joins(:answers).reorder("count(answers.id) DESC").group(:id)
  }
end
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank for sharing your answer Shane.  While the code executes, unfortunately the ordering of what is being shown isn't changing at all.  I even tried it after uncommenting my `default_scope` set to to show whats created last first.  I pasted more code into my question body in case it helps.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't realize there was a default scope on `Question`. This method should use `reorder` instead. I've edited it accordingly. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Thanks for editing.. unfortunately still not working.  I want to make sure that the way Im calling it in the controller is correct: `@questions = @course.questions.by_answer_count`.  In my view I then call to `render @questions`.

Comment: That looks correct to me. Try opening the console `rails console` and executing `Course.find(id).questions.by_answer_count` and see if the order clause is being applied to the SQL statement.

Comment: Great debug tip.  I am getting the error "undefined method `by_answer_count'" when doing the query in rails console.

Comment: Got it to work!  I someone had not been using the `index` function on courses, hence it wasn't applying to the controller.  Thanks again